# Remove all punctuation except underline between characters in R with POSIX character class

Tags: r, posix, gsub

I would like to use R to remove all underlines expect those between words. At the end the code removes underlines at the end or at the beginning of a word.
The result should be
**'hello_world and hello_world'**.
I want to use those pre-built classes. Right know I have learn to expect particular characters with following code but I don't know how to use the word boundary sequences.

```
test<-"hello_world and _hello_world_"
gsub("[^_[:^punct:]]", "", test, perl=T)
```

Comment: This `[:punct:]` is so slick: "*Negated versions, such as `[:^alpha:]` use `\P` instead of `\p`.*" ([PCRE reference](https://www.pcre.org/original/pcre.txt))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
gsub("[^_[:^punct:]]|_+\\b|\\b_+", "", test, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hq2ZTh/2)

*Details*:

- `[^_[:^punct:]]` - any punctuation except `_`
- `|` - or
- `_+\b` - one or more `_` at the end of a word
- `|` - or
- `\b_+` - one or more `_` at the start of a word

Answer (score 0):

One non-regex way is to split and use `trimws` by setting the `whitespace` argument to `_`, i.e.

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(test, ' '), function(i)trimws(i, whitespace = '_')), collapse = ' ')
#[1] "hello_world and hello_world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
test <- "hello_world and _hello_world_"
output <- gsub("(?<![^\\W])_|_(?![^\\W])", "", test, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "hello_world and hello_world"
```

Explanation of regex:

```
(?<![^\\W])  assert that what precedes is a non word character OR the start of the input
_            match an underscore to remove
|            OR
_            match an underscore to remove, followed by
(?![^\\W])   assert that what follows is a non word character OR the end of the input
```

Comment: Note that `(?<![^\\W])` is the same as `(?<!\\w)` and `(?![^\\W])`  is the same as `(?!\\w)`. Using `(?<![^\\W])` and `(?![^\\W])` is only good when you plan to add exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove all the underlying which has a word boundary on either of the end. We use positive lookahead and lookbehind regex to find such underlyings. To remove underlying at the start and end we use `trimws`.

```
test<-"hello_world and _hello_world_"
gsub("(?<=\\b)_|_(?=\\b)", "", trimws(test, whitespace = '_'), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "hello_world and hello_world"
```

Comment: Note that `(?<=\\b)` is the same as  `(?=\\b)` and both are the same as `\\b`, since it is a zero-width assertion.